# ORA-00904: "Extent1"."MODIFIED_DATE": invalid identifier

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle11g, entity-framework-4

I am trying to publish my code to the server. The code is running but I am getting some error in certain pages.

**Error:** ORA-00904: "Extent1"."MODIFIED_DATE": invalid identifier
There is no such table in the database called Extent1.

**Expected behaviour:** The code is running perfectly when I am running it in development. The code is also running perfectly when I publish it in a different server. It should running perfectly in the new server.

In the stacktrace I am shown that the error occurs here

> BBS.Models.ObjectManager.UserManager.GetDivision() in E:\Final
>   BBS\BBS\Models\ObjectManager\UserManager.cs:136

Below is given the code

```
public List<PDSDIVISION> GetDivision()
{
    Entities2 db = new Entities2();
    IQueryable<PDSDIVISION> idivisions = from e in db.PDSDIVISIONs where e.IS_INTERNAL != 1 select e;
    List<PDSDIVISION> divisions = idivisions.ToList();
    return divisions;
}
```

The PDSDIVISION columns are ->

- DIVKEY
- DIVNAME
- BDIVNAME
- IS_INTERNAL
- DIVCODE
- LAND_AREA
- RIVER_AREA
- FOREST_AREA
- COMMT_ENG_NAME
- COMMT_BN_NAME
- CARD_TYPE
- REMARKS
- CREATED_BY
- CREATED_DATE
- MODIFIED_BY
- MODIFIED_DATE

I am using entity framework 4 and oracle 11g database.

Comment: Which EF method you're using (Code First or DB First)? Can you see what kind of SQL query generated by EF in debug to make sure `Extent1` alias exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check the column name in the Model class. I had a similar issue, and resolved it by checking each name line by line.

In my case the issue was a additional two characters. EG:

```
   [Column("PROCESSED_DATE")]
    DateTime DateProcessed { get; set; }
```

needed to be corrected to :

```
   [Column("PROCESS_DATE")]
    DateTime DateProcessed { get; set; }
```